# Django JWT authentication does not load all the protected urls

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

When i login using my api in the swagger and fill in the information in the Authorize button pop up, my api list which is protected still does not appear.

I tried adding it as 'Bearer token', but it do not work.

Following is my code:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
 'LOGIN_URL': 'api:login',
 'LOGOUT_URL': 'api:logout',
 'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
 'DOC_EXPANSION': 'list',
 'APIS_SORTER': 'alpha',
 'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
     'api_key': {
         'type': 'apiKey',
         'in': 'header',
         'name': 'Authorization',
         "description": "JWT authorization"
     }
 },
}


'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
],

# Permission settings
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
],
```

I am using django-rest-swagger==2.2.0. It works in swagger 2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

in your root urls.py  s

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
openapi.Info(
  x,
  y,
  z,
  ),
public=True,
permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)
```

you should check if it has `permission_classes`  set to AllowAny! or you just forget to add them!

p.s. It's too late but maybe helps others!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue, Django swagger, that wont work for protected(Token authenticated) APIs, Use drf-yasf instead, with same configuration 
follow the ink below

```
https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg
```